# Variadic constexpr type-selector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr

Sorry for the pompous name, I would like to create a `constexpr` function, which accepts a variable number of *boolean* template arguments, and returns the "template index" of the first `true` value, in C++11 (C++14 only solutions welcome but won't be accepted as the answer).

For example, calling this function `Selector`

```
Selector< false, false >() == 0 // none of the template argument is true
Selector< true, false, true >() == 1 // first true template argument is the first one
Selector< false, false, true, false >() == 3 // .. and here it's the third one
```

A typical use of this, and the reason why I call it a "type-selector", would be

```
Selector< std::is_pointer<T>::value, std::is_arithmetic<T>::value >()
```

and the reason why I'd like it to be a `constexpr` is for use in partial template specialisation.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this, although I think that using variadic templates, constexpr template specialisation (for the 0 case), and recursion (is it possible to "consume" template arguments, like `shift` in bash?), this should be doable.

Comment: Downvote please explain...

Comment: It's a good question. But it lacks effort...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Agreed, I'm trying to come up with something now.

Comment: note: in the recursion you can pass how many arguments you have checked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer by @CoffeeandCode, here is another example that works as expected using `constexpr` recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<bool B0=false, bool... Bs>
constexpr std::size_t Selector( std::size_t I = 1 )
{
    return B0 ? I : Selector<Bs...>(I+1);
}

template<>
constexpr std::size_t Selector<false>( std::size_t I )
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< Selector() << std::endl;
    std::cout<< Selector<false,false>() << std::endl;
    std::cout<< Selector<true,false,true>() << std::endl;
    std::cout<< Selector<false,false,true,false>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t I, bool... Bs>
struct selector;

template <std::size_t I, bool... Bs>
struct selector<I, true, Bs...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

template <std::size_t I, bool... Bs>
struct selector<I, false, Bs...> : selector<I+1, Bs...> {};

template <std::size_t I>
struct selector<I> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <bool... Bs>
constexpr std::size_t Selector()
{
    return selector<1, Bs...>::value;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa4c79b0dd1aa28f)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't satisfied that the answer wasn't purely a `constexpr` function. So I re-wrote it in recursion that a C++11 compliant compiler will accept:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t I = 1>
constexpr std::size_t selector(bool value = false){
    return value ? I : 0;
}

template<std::size_t I = 1, typename ... Bools>
constexpr std::size_t selector(bool first, bool second, Bools ... others){
    return first ? I : selector<I+1>(second, others...);
}
```

This would be called with functional syntax rather than templates, and will always be `constexpr` because of the template parameter being incremented.

Comment: Slightly different syntax, and the input types are not limited to `bool`s, but that works too :)